# How to ensure transient DI services are chained correctly

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

Okay, so more than anything I think I either have a terminology issue here or otherwise I need some help understanding why what I'm thinking of is not such a good idea. Unfortunately, I'm self-taught so often my terminology is wrong or old-fashioned. I've no problem accepting that some of the code I produce contains quite a few smells, but I want to understand what makes it smelly so that I can attack the most risky parts first.

I've been making some use of the DI functionality baked into .NET in recent years, mostly for injection of singletons into MVC controllers. I'm now trying to make better and more expansive use of DI, and especially to stamp out the remaining places where I've got business logic directly in actions on controllers.

So currently, I have no issue getting an `ILogger<ControllerType>` and a singleton of `IDatabase` (not really called that but you get the idea) injected into controllers. Within the controller constructor, I then create an instance of, for example, `ReallyUsefulHelper` that takes an `ILogger` and an `IDatabase` in it's own constructor. That's very handy, as then the logging from within `ReallyUsefulHelper` has the controller scope and it's clear in the log output as to which controller the call inside `ReallyUsefulHelper` came from.

I'm aware though that controllers themselves are transient (new instance for every request) and some of my services like `ImportantButLessCommonlyUsedHelper` might be a little expensive to instantiate, so I want to inject `ReallyUsefulHelper` transiently, and perhaps her cousin `ImportantButLessCommonlyUsedHelper` scoped. Of course, there's many more different such services across the application but you get the idea.

My question is - is there some way to have the controller's `ILogger<T>` instance injected into the `IHelper` instance during instantiation by the DI container? If so, what would this approach be called, so I can read more about it? If there's something wrong with this, what is it so that I can understand better? It seems clunky to me to pass an `ILogger` to each method in the `IHelper` that needs it which would otherwise get the job done. I have seen lower level libraries that provide a delegate for you to attach your `ILogger.Log()` method to but this also seems clunky and unnecessary for my purpose.

Comment: What you're looking for is called `Service Locator` but it is considered an anti-pattern. So you would inject a DI container and then each time your `ReallyUsefulHelper` needs a logger or starts a scope it would resolve one from the DI container.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, although I expect your request-based logger concept to not be that easily implemented using MS.DI. There's a part in your question that triggered me though, which is: "some of my services [...] might be a little expensive to instantiate". Please note you [injection constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) so that you can [compose object graphs with confidence](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).